# Accessing child objects

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm new to JavaScript and I'm currently running into an issue trying to access child objects within a parent.

in the below example I'm looking at trying to access the last object within the parent object (in this case customer) to allow me to add more key and value paris into it.

```js
  {
    "orderNo": "12345678",
    "Date": "29/07/2021",
    "trackingno": "TN0039291",
    "custid": "2345",
    "customer": {
      "custid": "2345"
    }
  }
```

Comment: give all example not only json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using ES6, you can do this

```
parentObj = {
  ...parentObj,
  customer: {
    ...parentObj.customer,
    newField: itsValue,
  }
}
```

Comment: You basically duplicate the whole object to add a single property, then destroy the old version when you replace it with your new copy. A pretty costly way of doing things.

Comment: This is just best practice in ES6 and recent ECMAScript
if the parentObj is const , this is so important and use new name (new variable) not parentObj.

in JS ES6 , variable are most likely declared with const and will need spreed syntax to use the copy of it before modifying it.

Comment: Aha. The best practice is to squander CPU and memory just to pretend JavaScript can handle immutable objects while it actually can't. Why don't you change your post and say: "you must do this" instead of "you can do this"?

Answer (score 1):

Just do like this

```
parentObj["customer"]["newProperty"] = valueOfTheNewProperty;
```